# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' when compiling GooglePlayServices with 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv'

Tags: android, ffmpeg, javacv, javacpp

I'm merging audio with video by compiling **compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '1.1'** and everything works fine.

But when i try to compile `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'` with it ,its giving this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   non-zero exit value 2

Build.gradle

> 

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.id"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jniLibs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

Comment: post your `build.gradle`

Comment: what about `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'` //7.8.0 ??

Comment: its giving same error on 7.8.0
iam trying to enter build.gradle code but unable to add in comments. how can i do that?

Comment: Add build.gradle in your question section .

Comment: call `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'`

Comment: Let me inform please .

Comment: same error @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'`

Comment: its still not working 
i have tried 
 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.3.0'
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
and now its working. seems like its conflicting with appCompact-v7

Comment: anyways thanks a lot.